# insert ... select ... on duplicate key update + delete obsolete rows

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

I need to update a table with pre-calculated values from tables where data can be added/updated/deleted.

I could use

```
insert into precalculated(...)
select ... from ...
on duplicate key update ...
```

to add/update the pre-calculated table but is there an optimized method to delete the obsolete rows ?

Comment: when you say obsolete you mean rows that where not updated using this script?

Comment: I mean the data which were deleted from the main tables. The data deleted from the main tables should be deleted from the pre calculated table. so basically, yes, the data which were not updated.

Comment: Create a trigger on the table you are deleting that checks if there are "orphan" rows and delete them

Comment: It could do the job. I may even change my whole approach to use only triggers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found my solution using rename.

so basically, I will do a simple insert select to the temporary table and then

```
rename precalculated to precalculated_temprename, precalculated_temp to precalculated, precalculated_temprename to precalculated_temp;
truncate precalculated_temp;
```

need some tests but it seems the rename operation is fast and atomic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a stored procedure that deletes the data of your related tables if and only if the records fulfill a condition.

There's not enough information in your question to design the procedure, but I can give you a little example:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure delete_orphans()
begin
    declare id_orphan int;
    declare done int default false;
    declare cur_orphans cursor for
        select distinct d.id
        from data as d
            left join precalculated as p on d.id = p.id
        where p.id is null;
    declare continue handler for not found set done = true;
    open cur_orphans;
    loop_delete_orphans: loop
        fetch cur_orphans into id_orphan;
        if done then
            leave cur_orphans;
        end if;
        delete from data where id = id_orphan;
    end loop;
    close cur_orphans;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

This procedure will delete every row in the `data` table that does not have at least one related row in the `precalculated` table.

Of course, this approach might be inneficient, because it will delete the rows one by one, but as I said this is only an example. You can customize it to fit your needs.

You can call this procedure from a trigger if you want (with `call delete_orphans()`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is the other way. I wan't to delete from precalculated rows which were deleted from the main tables / are not used anymore. anyway yes, I can compare data using left join and delete rows from precalculated but I needed to know if I could find something more elegant. seems like not...

Comment: however, I may go for the trigger solution. as I replied to Andreas  Wederbrand, "I think this is how I will end doing it. But I will still need some scripts to clean the table since the precalculated data also depend on date (I Want to delete rows which are not between begin and end date) and some counters.". not as elegant as I would like but it should work. thank you.

Comment: @medmed You can create a stored procedure to delete the rows that you don't need anymore, and you can call that stored procedure from your trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are always adding or updating rows that exist in these other tables, and you want to remove any rows that don't exist, why don't you just :

```
DELETE FROM precalculated
insert into precalculated(...)
select ... from ...
on duplicate key update ...
```

Always starting clean means you don't have to worry about orphans later.

Comment: I can't delete data from this table. that would break the service until the data have been restored.

Comment: it won't if you encapsulate the whole statement into single transaction

Answer (score 1):

You could add triggers for insert, delete and update on the main tables that maintains `precalculated`.

When inserting or updating the same code can be used to calculate the values and issuing a `replace into precalculated (...) values (...)`

When deleting it's probably the same, with the addition that you'll also delete rows from `precalculated` that are orphans. Be smart here and use values from the original delete to query `precalculated` for orphans instead of doing a table scan.

Comment: I think this is how I will end doing it. But I will still need some scripts to clean the table since the precalculated data also depend on date (I Want to delete rows which are not between begin and end date) and some counters. thanks.